# Send spinner data to database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-spinner

I am trying to send data to database from a spinner I initialize the database like this `SPINNER + " TYPE ";`

And in insert data method I put it as `Type spinner` but this line gives me an error `contentValues.put(SPINNER, spinner);`

what should I put there instead of `put`

```
public boolean insertData(String fname, String lname, String pnumber, String email, String nic, Type spinner) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(FNAME, fname);
            contentValues.put(LNAME, lname);
            contentValues.put(PNUMBER, pnumber);
            contentValues.put(EMAIL, email);
            contentValues.put(NIC, nic);
            contentValues.put(SPINNER, spinner);

            long result = db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, contentValues);
            return result != -1;
        }
```

Comment: What is `Type`? You can't save in the column SPINNER class objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to save a spinner object in the database which of course fails.
Change the data type of the column `SPINNER` to `TEXT` in the table:

```
...SPINNER + " TEXT";
```

Also change the data type of the argument `spinner` to `String` in the definition of `insertData()`:

```
public boolean insertData(String fname, String lname, String pnumber, String email, String nic, String spinner)
```

When you call `insertData()` pass the selected item of the spinner instead of the spinner itself:

```
insertData(....., yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
```

Now uninstall the app from the device to delete the database and rerun so it is recreated with the proper data type for the column `SPINNER`.

Comment: Should i initialize myspinner as a EditText `EditText id,fname,lname,pnumber,email,nic,myspinner;`

Comment: Isn't it a Spinner?

Comment: If it is an EditText then initialize it like your comment. From the name of the variable I assumed it is a spinner. If it is an EditText I must edit the answer.